# Roots of unity has length 1?

Tags: complex-analysis

It seems to be the case that if $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a root of unity, i.e. $z^k=1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then $z$ lies on the unit circle in the complex plane, in other words $|z|=1$.

Let $z=a+bi$ be such that $z^k=1$, how can I show that $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1$?

Comment: Note $|z^k|=1$.

Comment: Simply $|z|^k=|z^k|=1$.

Comment: I know $|z^k|=|1|=1$, but why is $|z^k|=|z|^k$?

Comment: Generally, $|xy|=|x||y|$. You can see this by computing both sides of the equation.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks, I'm unstuck.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Suppose $\lvert z\rvert \neq 1$. What can you say about $\lvert z^k\rvert$?

Comment: Huh? Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

As the modulus of a complex number is a multiplicative function, the modulus of a  $k$-th root of unity is a *positive real* root of unity. Do you know many of them?